# Blank screen boot after UPDATE

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

I have Ubuntu 14.04, with an Nvidia 740M card, I installed propriety drivers as well as bumblebee and everything was working great, I did an update the other day, restarted, and once it displays the the Ubuntu splash, it goes black and I can't log in? I have no idea what to do, I really don't want to have to purge the nvidia drivers and install something else, can anyone help me maintain my propriety drivers and fix this at the same time? I am assuming it is the Nvidia drivers that is causing the problem...

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if your system is running (switch to a text terminal or try to ssh to your box)
2. bumblebee is not needed any more, just bbswitch.

I get also this black screen after every start of the X-Server, I suppose there is something broken with the initialization of the screen, most of the time this gets fixed, when I push the system to standby and back to operation, then the screen gets a proper set up.

Comment: Thanks @gorgooger . System is running and I can log in via terminal. I'll remove bumblebee so long. How do you push the screen back and forth between standby and operation?